# Git says 'commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches', but also 'nothing to commit'

Tags: git

I'm trying to switch branches from `test1` to `test2` by running `git checkout test2`, but am getting this error:

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    path/to/file.xml
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Even though, when I run `git status` or `git commit` on `test1`, I get this:

```
On branch test1
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Interestingly, I can switch between `master` and `test1` no problem.

What's going on here? What do I need to do to switch to `test2`?

Comment: You have to add the changed file first, only then it will be recognized by `git commit`. Or you advice `git commit` to add all changed files before commit: `git commit -a`. However the latter is IMHO not a good way, as you often accidentally add and commit files you did not want to commit.

Comment: is this file `path/to/file.xml` being git ignored in `test1` branch? If so, you can just go to the folder and delete the file if you don't need it.

Comment: Have you used `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git update-index --skip-worktree`? (If `path/to/file.xml` is untracked, Git should have used the word "untracked" in the error message, I think, hence this question.)

Comment: @torek yes I had used `skip-worktree` on `file.xml`, but toggling it on/off doesn't seem to affect or fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: Skip worktree is a persistent setting. To clear it, run `git update-index --no-skip-worktree` on the same file. (I think it would be nice if `git status` had a way to show these bits, because they do matter here.) Once you clear it, things should become, er, clearer. :-)

Comment: @torek right I'm saying I tried turning it off and it doesn't fix my problem

Comment: Once it's off, you should be able to tell that the file is modified: `git status` will say there are changes in it. That's why Git is complaining that the file is modified and yet not committed.

Comment: @torek I see now. You're right the file now shows up in `git status`. Thanks! Like you said it would be nice if git gave you this info when you run `git status`.

Comment: @torek make you comment an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You need to clear the skip-worktree bit and re-run `git status` to see what's going on.  From that point forward, things will be (somewhat) clearer.

#### Long(ish)

The problem here was that the skip-worktree bit was set on:

```
path/to/file.xml
```

There's a related bit spelled assume-unchanged.  Both bits have the same actual effect.  Neither is meant for the way people tend to use them, though documentation and stackoverflow answers recommend the skip-worktree bit,<sup>1</sup> and so do I here; but either one does the same thing in practice.  You do have to remember (or re-discover) which bit you set, in order to clear it:

```
git update-index --no-skip-worktree path/to/file.xml
```

When either bit is set on a file whose name and contents are recorded in the index, Git assumes that the contents stored via the index should be used, and the work-tree copy should be ignored during `git status` and `git add` operations.

Fortunately, Git is smart enough to check the actual work-tree copy on *other* operations.  If Git is about to *overwrite* the work-tree copy for some reason—such as `git checkout` or `git merge` of a commit whose committed copy of that file differs from the current index copy—Git will double-check that the *work-tree* copy of `path/to/file.xml` matches the index copy.  If not, Git will complain that the operation will overwrite the work-tree copy.

Unfortunately, `git status`, by design, *doesn't* announce that the work-tree copy is out of sync with the index copy.  It just assumes that both versions of the file match.  So you run `git status` and there's no changes to commit and hence nothing to save, but meanwhile `git checkout` or `git merge` keeps complaining that you must commit your changes.

Clearing the bit, whichever bit it is, makes `git status` notice the problem.  It seems to me that `git status` should be more informative here: it needs to say, perhaps when using an extra option or perhaps just always, that there *is* some difference here but it's being deliberately ignored due to one or both of these bits.  (To make this work well with sparse checkout, it probably should say nothing about a marked-`--skip-worktree`-file that's in the index, not in the work-tree, and excluded by the sparseness rules.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Assume-unchanged is meant for use on file systems where the `lstat` call is particularly slow, and Git is allowed to ignore it.  Skip-worktree is meant for use with sparse checkout, and Git is *not* allowed to ignore this.  Git has no user-oriented sparse checkout commands either, so setting the skip-worktree bit is better.

Answer (score -4):

Git reset solved it for me:

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When offering a solution like this one be sure to include warnings about its effects. Think about if someone trying this might lose work, or what else they might need to know before running a command like this.

Comment: Please do not make such a dangerous offer to  anyone else again